# Blogger HTML/javascript gadget

Tags: html, blogger

In Blogger, there is an HTML/javascript gadget:  What would be the exact code to add in an email address at Comcast.net in the gadget?  I have no experience with javascript, and need to re enter the code for a contact email.  PLEASE help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the following HTML to display a clickable Email link -

```
<a href="mailto:nowhere@mozilla.org">Send email to nowhere</a>
```

Replace the email address with your own. If the readers have an email client, then that will open when the above link is clicked. In case you need a preset with the subject and body text defined, then the code will change as follows -

```
<a href="mailto:nowhere@mozilla.org?subject=The%20subject&amp;body=The%20body">
  Send mail subject and body
</a>
```

Reference - [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#E-mail_links)

Otherwise, you can also implement the native Contact Gadget provided Blogger, to make it easier for the readers to contact you directly via the page itself.